# Optimize laggy resize

Tags: javascript, window-resize

I'm having some trouble figuring out this problem, but I reckon it might be quite common, or have a well-known solution. I did some research but I can't quite see how to proceed here.

I have a page with a series of slides, and a small js script to go from one to the other:
http://analucia.net/test/index2.html

The slides have a `max-width: 100%;` (and height) so they're resized witht the rest of the window. This is very simple and works very well with 2 or 3 images, but with 30 it becomes extremely laggy, especially with large screen sizes.

I guess manually resizing the window create a lot of events that become overwhelming, especially with large pictures. My intuition would be to use some javascript to "transcribe" all these events into one or two, and thus handle the window resizing in an orderly way. 
I found this: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/
but it looks quite specific, and I'm not sure it could apply here

So my questions would be:

1. Would this kind of approach be a good solution to this problem?
2. My understanding of js is extremely limited and I wouldn't know where to begin to even apply that idea of having a script to get the resize information, so to speak

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The solution would be probably to not have 30 images on the page at the same time. If they are at 100%, i bet you can only see one or two, the rest can be hidden ( less rendering ). And CSS is nearly always faster as JS as it was designed for exactly that usecase (styling things).

Comment: @Jonas W. Thank you. This really makes way more sense... I should have thought of this. Thanks a lot